# KendoUI TabStrip on click

Tags: kendo-ui, tabs, kendo-tabstrip

I have a little problem with using KendoUI TabStrip. It doesn't matter if I'm at the top of the screen, but when I click a tab, the screen moves to the tabs to the center of the screen and the I have to scroll to view the content, this is not a big problem, but it is annoying, so I would like to know if there's a way to avoid this.

Thank you.

Comment: can you add some codes plz..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to Telerik:

> The problem is caused by the fact that during the time that the tabs
>   are changed, the page get smaller, so the scroll position goes up. The
>   solution is to set height or min-height style to the TabStrip content
>   s, so that the overall TabStrip height remains constant.

They also list other potential solutions in the following thread:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/tabstrip/browser-scroll-position-is-changed-when-tab-is-changed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with tabs jumping around when i was removing and adding tabstrips dynamically.

My root cause was due to using jquery and trying to do a $("#tabstrip").remove() instead of clearing out the container holding the tabstrip. My fix was $("#tabstripcontainer").empty() to clear out any remnants that the tabstrip left behind.